# Viewpager with data from asynctask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

So I am making an app which pulls a story from a server. The story arrives split into parts. I want to put each story part on a different ViewPager page, but what I've tried so far either makes the app crash or just gives me a blank screen.

This is my code for that activity:

```
package com.firegaming.myfirstapp;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class ContinueStoryActivity extends FragmentActivity {


private ProgressDialog pDialog;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
private static int partCounter;
private static String storyID;
ArrayList<String> storyPartList = new ArrayList<>();
FragmentStatePagerAdapter adapter;
ViewPager pager;
JSONArray parts = null;

private static final String GET_STORY_URL = "http://firegaming.host56.com/get_story.php";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
private static final String TAG_PARTS = "parts";
private static final String TAG_PARTCOUNT = "partCount";
private static final String TAG_STORYID = "storyID";
private static final String TAG_STORYTEXT = "storyText";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_continue_story);


    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    new GetStory().execute();

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_continue_story, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        return StoryFragment.newInstance(storyPartList.get(pos).toString());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return storyPartList.size();
    }

    public int getItemPosition(Object object){
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {
        //do nothing here! no call to super.restoreState(arg0, arg1);
    }
}



    class GetStory extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ContinueStoryActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Story...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args){
        int success;
        try{

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", MainActivity.USERNAME));

            Log.d("Request!", "Starting!");

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(GET_STORY_URL, "GET", params);

            Log.d("Story Attempt", json.toString());
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1){

                parts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PARTS);
                partCounter = Integer.parseInt(json.getString(TAG_PARTCOUNT));
                storyID = json.getString(TAG_STORYID);
                return json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS);

            } else {

                Log.d("Story Get Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }

        } catch (JSONException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        pDialog.dismiss();

        if (file_url != null) {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < parts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = parts.getJSONObject(i);
                    int id = c.getInt(TAG_STORYID);
                    String storyText = c.getString(TAG_STORYTEXT);
                    storyPartList.add(id-1, storyText);
                }
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

    }

}


}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:
When not returning null, as was suggested, the app crashes again.
These are all the errors that come up in logcat when the app crashes.

```
01-03 12:29:19.298  29861-29861/com.firegaming.myfirstapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.firegaming.myfirstapp, PID: 29861
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.firegaming.myfirstapp.ContinueStoryActivity$MyPagerAdapter.getItem(ContinueStoryActivity.java:88)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:105)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:837)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:987)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(ViewPager.java:447)
        at com.firegaming.myfirstapp.ContinueStoryActivity$GetStory.onPostExecute(ContinueStoryActivity.java:163)
        at com.firegaming.myfirstapp.ContinueStoryActivity$GetStory.onPostExecute(ContinueStoryActivity.java:99)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Because `if (success == 1)` you `return null` so you do not see anything :-)

Comment: yes, you're not returning anything after your success.

Comment: Okay, I changed it so that it returns, as you can see in my edit, and now it does crash.  I also added the logcat errors.

Comment: I am suspicious of the fact that `storyPartList` is a hasmap with id's dictated be the incoming data. If the incoming id's for instance is [0,2,3] then `getItem(1)` will fail. What happens if you let `storyPartList`simply be an arraylist (as the name sort of suggests that it is)?

Comment: The way it is set up on the web, the ID's will always start from 1 and go to whichever number, with nothing missing inbetween.

Comment: Then that might not be a problem, it is just an unnecessary complexity. Keeping track of the Id's that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a list of suggestions:

I am suspicious of the fact that storyPartList is a hasmap with id's dictated be the incoming data. If the incoming id's for instance is [0,2,3] then getItem(1) will fail. What happens if you let storyPartListsimply be an arraylist (as the name sort of suggests that it is)?

The `getCount` of adapter is similarly dictated by the incoming data:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return partCounter;
}
```

Instead let the counter depend on the actual size of `storyPartList`:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return storyPartList.size();
}
```

Now, having the pager data being determined purely by the amount of data added to `storyPartList`, I would suggest creating the pager once in `onCreate()` instead of re-creating it each time you add a story:

```
ViewPager pager;
FragmentStatePagerAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_continue_story);
    new GetStory().execute();

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager())
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And in `onPostExecute` now simply do:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This will make the adapter refresh it's contents based on the content of `storyPartList`. To make the adapter update correctly you might have to add this to `MyPagerAdapter`:

```
public int getItemPosition(Object object){
     return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

**Summary of suggestions**

- Make storyPartList be a List instead of Map
- Let getCount return storyPartList.size()
- Create the pager in onCreate and call notifyDataSetChanged when adding a story
- Finally implement getItemPosition in the adapter to make it update correctly

Comment: I've implemented all your suggestions (my post is edited to reflect them in the code), and while it now doesn't crash anymore, it still only displays a blank white screen.

Comment: Okay, this does work, I just was doing stupid things later on.  The code as it is now is functional thanks to the changes you suggested.  Thank you!

Comment: Cool np :) happy coding

Comment: As a final note, you might want to do: `if (adapter != null) adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` since being called inside an asynctask. Then the adapter might be null if one opens the story page and press back before the asynctask completes

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all is well with your web service and you're parsing the data correctly, add the following code to your `MyPagerAdapter` class:

```
@Override
public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {
        //do nothing here! no call to super.restoreState(arg0, arg1);
}
```

First try this and see if it works ... also please post the logcat of your crash.

Three more things you need to ensure:

1. Make sure that the `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and `android.app.Fragment` classes are not used together. Use everything from the v4 support library only.
2. Make sure that `getCount()` returns the actual number of fragments corresponding to your `getItem(int index)` method: use `storyPartList.size()` in `getCount()`.
3. As [cYrixmorten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1501613/cyrixmorten) has suggested, make `storyPartList` an `ArrayList` and call `storyPartList.add(...)` instead of `storyPartList.put(...)`.

Comment: I added that, but it doesn't seem to make much of a difference. I know for a fact all is fine on the web service side of things, since I was tracing the code and could see the correct values being returned there.

Comment: `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` is used everywhere, and `android.app.Fragment` nowhere.  Just made double sure about that.    `getCount()` gets it's value from the values pulled down from the internet and should always correspond to the amount of story parts and thus how many fragments should appear.

Comment: ok cool ... we are narrowing down the number of possible errors ... now pls see re-edited post.